# Homotopy equivalence re-definition

Tags: algebraic-topology

Homotopy equivalence is defined thus: Two spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent if there are continuous maps $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ with $gf \sim \textbf{1}_X$ and $fg \sim \textbf{1}_Y$.

I am rephrasing my question: If we said the image of $f$ can be deformed continuously to $1_Y$ and the same with $g$ deformed to $1_X$.

Would such a definition be even useful?

Comment: But $f$ and $1_Y$ have different domains, so $f\sim 1_Y$ doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: To define a homotopy between two functions, they must have the same domain and codomain.  [Homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy)

Comment: What is your definition of $f\sim 1_Y$?  Please add that definition to your question because, right now, $f\sim 1_Y$ is nonsense.

Comment: If the image of $f$ is continuously deformed into $1_Y$ is what I meant.

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't make sense because the image of $f$ can't be deformed into the function $1_Y$.  Perhaps you mean that the image of $f$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$.  I believe that this is the same as saying the image is a retract.

Comment: Yes, I think I do mean that. Suppose images of $f$ and $g$ were retracts of $Y$ and $X$, would it make the two spaces "equivalent" in anyway?

Comment: No, I only mean if some meaningful relationship can be had between the two spaces, not the fundamental group or anything that would use homotopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you are asking: if there exist maps $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to X$ such that $Y$ deformation retracts onto the image of $f$, and $X$ deformation retracts onto the image of $g$, then are $X$ and $Y$ homotopy equivalent?

(It's the only reasonable interpretation I can make of the question and the follow-up comments. But to be honest I don't understand why you would expect that to be true: there is absolutely no reason $f$ and $g$ are related in this scenario, and there are immediate counterexamples as you will see. If I got the question wrong, please clarify your question and ask it in precise terms, without any vagueness...)

The answer is no. Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^1$ be the exponential map, and $g : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a constant map. Then $f$ is surjective, so its image is the whole of $\mathbb{S}^1$ and of course there's a deformation retraction; and $\mathbb{R}$ deformation retracts onto a point (the image of $g$). But $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1$ are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Yes, you understood right. I did not mean they were "homotopy" equivalent, but equivalent or related in some other loose way. You just showed with your example that there is no such connection. Thank you. But what if $g$ in your example were not the constant map, is there a counter-example?